# Inputs are disapperaing in my frames.

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 3 frames and each frame has a few textinput boxes and some checkmarks that I created. Every time I click to go to next frame my inputs and check marks erase on previous frame . Is there a way to keep he text in my textinputs while I move through my frames?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variables should do the job

```
var firstcontent = "mycontent";
var secondcontent = "mycontent"; ...
```

Comment: I found out how to do it.. thanks for the help.. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1132361?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the same instance name for the same inputs in each frames